# how do i know youtube live is enabled?

Tags: php, youtube-data-api, google-api-php-client

I am creating YouTube Live broadcast link using

```
https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveBroadcasts/insert?apix=true
```

I need to check Connected User's YouTube live is enabled or not? not able to find any endpoint here please help.

Comment: Do you means user have upcoming video or something?

Comment: No. i means youtube live enabled or not.  please check given link error details. __liveStreamingNotEnabled__

Comment: Check this if this is something helps you https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/liveBroadcasts?part=id%2Csnippet%2Cstatus&mine=true&broadcastStatus=active&key={YOUR_API_KEY}